# aframevr how to open url

Tags: aframe, webvr

Using AFrame VR is it possible to "click" a link within the VR scene?

We are trying to build a world where the viewer can gaze on an object, this will then open a URL in the current tab with another VR world in.

These URL's will all be on the same domain.

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like we can use this:

https://github.com/gasolin/aframe-href-component

e.g.

```
<a-box id="orange-cube" position="0 3.5 -2" rotation="30 30 0" width="2" depth="2" height="2" color="#F16745" href="https://github.com/gasolin/aframe-href-component"></a-box>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use this Javascript from Mozilla's hyperlink demo: https://github.com/321C4/aframe-link-demo/blob/master/js/aframe-hyperlink.js

Just copy it into your project and you'll be able to use it as they did in their demo.

Answer (score 0):

[aframe-href-component](https://github.com/gasolin/aframe-href-component) is build for that use case. Check the [second example](https://gasolin.github.io/aframe-href-component/) which allow you gaze on an object, then open a URL in the current tab.

Beyond this web-like way, there is a work-in-progress WebVR standard to loading VR space with the hyperlink. Follow https://github.com/aframevr/aframe/issues/403 for latest support progress with aframe.

(relative disclosure: I'm the creator of [aframe-href-component](https://github.com/gasolin/aframe-href-component) module)

Comment: Thanks buddy! We came across your stuff a couple of weeks ago, love it, nice one!